# Programatically created a workItem in Azure devops but can't see it in the list

Tags: rest, azure-devops

This is my code:

```
var personalAccessToken = "...";
var orgUrl = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/my-org");
var teamProjectName = "myproj";

VssHttpMessageHandler.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("localhost:18080");

VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));


// Create instance of WorkItemTrackingHttpClient using VssConnection
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

try
{
    JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();

    //add fields and their values to your patch document
    patchDocument.Add(
        new JsonPatchOperation()
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/fields/System.Title",
            Value = "Test WorkItem"
        }
    );

    patchDocument.Add(
        new JsonPatchOperation()
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps",
            Value = ""
        }
    );

    patchDocument.Add(
        new JsonPatchOperation()
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority",
            Value = "1"
        }
    );

    patchDocument.Add(
        new JsonPatchOperation()
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity",
            Value = "2 - High"
        }
    );

    patchDocument.Add(
        new JsonPatchOperation()
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps",
            Value = "Test Repro Steps"
        }
    );

    

    WorkItem result = witClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, teamProjectName, "Bug").Result;

    Console.WriteLine("Bug Successfully Created: Bug #{0}", result.Id);
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error creating bug: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
}
```

It creates successfully (and running the code again gives an error about the item already existing with that name).

However when I go into azure devops in the browser, I cannot find any trace of the work item I created anywhere.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried your code, based on my test, actually the work item is not created because you try to update the field with reference name`'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps'` multiple times.

I get the following error message when debugging :

"`Error creating bug: VS403691: Update to work item -1 had two or more updates for field with reference name 'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps'. A field cannot be updated more than once in the same update.`"

Once I removed one of the `patchDocument`, the work item can be created successfully and I can see it in Azure DevOps work item list.

```
        patchDocument.Add(
            new JsonPatchOperation()
            {
                Operation = Operation.Add,
                Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps",
                Value = ""
            }
        );
```

In case you posted the wrong demo code, then please check your work item list area path and iteration path settings. If the work item query/list is based on a specific area path or iteration path which the new created work item is not included in, then you cannot see the new work item.

**UPDATE:**

We can get the list of work item fields used in a work item type by calling [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API. And the path should like this :"`/fields/field reference name`"

Below PowerShell script for your reference:

```
Param(
[string]$orgurl = “https://dev.azure.com/{organization}", 
[string]$project = “0424Test”,
[string]$wiID = “195”,
[string]$user = “”,
[string]$token = “PAT-Here”
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#List all fields
$baseUrl = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/$($wiID)?"+"$"+"expand=All&api-version=6.0"    
cls 
$wifields = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$wifields.fields
```

[image]

Comment: Ah you've cracked it, thanks. There are new errors now about certain required fields - you wouldn't happen to know where to get a list of Path values from for the various fields? I struggled on google to find a list of them.

Comment: @NibblyPig We can get the all fields a work item used by calling the work item REST API [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP). See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks that should do it, I assume I need them in the format `/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps"` for example, but I will investigate